# Timed data sent from python server to java client

Tags: java, python, multithreading, sockets

I am currently trying to send data from Python server to Java client.

- I've successfully connected the sockets (client to server)
- I can send messages from python server to java client and display them in terminal
- I can send messages from java client to python server and display them

**BUT** : I want to send the messages every 2 seconds for example.

SERVER:

```
while True:
   clientConnection.send(("Message from server" + "\r\n").encode());
   print("Message sent!");
   time.sleep(2);
```

CLIENT :

```
public void receiveData() {
    try {
        String receivedData = dataInputStream.readUTF();
        System.out.println(receivedData);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is the run() method:

```
public void run() {
    clientChannel.sendData();
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("message received");
        clientChannel.receiveData();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `"Message sent!"` is displayed in terminal every 2 seconds, but the client terminal is not receiving anything, just prints the `"message received"` one time and waits ..

Server output:

```
Server started successfully ! 
Hello
Message sent!
Message sent!
Message sent!
```

Client output:

```
message received
```

**EDIT** : The program works well if I delete the `time.sleep(2)` line.

Comment: How are you opening the socket on the java side of things?

Comment: Actually can you share what's happening on both sides? Sounds like the connection is being closed on the java side, and maybe the server keeps on sending. You could always tcp dump the port on the client side to make sure your packets are coming through.

Comment: I've already added the outputs from both sides :( the `Message sent!` is displayed every 2 seconds, but the client doesn't receive it. I didn't close any client connection because the messages are sent correctly if I remove the `time.sleep(2)` line .. :( . Here is the initialization I'm making:

   **socket = new Socket(serverHost, serverPort);**
   And
    **dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());**